# validation problem in asp.net login control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net login control in my web application.
I used the following code.

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginControl" runat="server" Width="351px" CssClass="login" 
        PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="You must enter a Password."
        UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="You must enter a Username."
         FailureText="Incorrect Username/Password"  
     EnableTheming="true" TitleText="Login into Focus/Career Status Viewer"  
     Height="164px" onauthenticate="LoginControl_Authenticate"   
         DisplayRememberMe="False" 
         UserNameLabelText="Username:" Font-Names="Arial" FailureTextStyle-Wrap="False" FailureAction="RedirectToLoginPage">
    <TextBoxStyle  CssClass="login-textbox" Font-Names="Arial" />
    <LoginButtonStyle  CssClass="login-button" />
   <ValidatorTextStyle Font-Names="Calibri" />
 <TitleTextStyle  CssClass="login-title"/>

</asp:Login>
     <br />
     <br />

<asp:ValidationSummary id="LoginValidationSummary"  
                        runat="server"  ShowSummary="true" 
         ValidationGroup="LoginControl" Height="44px" Width="471px"  >
                    </asp:ValidationSummary>
```

When I give the incorrect username and password and click the login button the failure text will appeared. Then clear the password field then click the login button both failure text and passwordrequirederrormessage validation messages will appeared. But I need only the password requirederrormessage will appeared. Can anyone able to give the solution for that. Thank you

Comment: I don't know what's wrong you have done , if you use default login control then it should work perfect as per you said

Answer (score 0):

You could always work around it, and use separate `Asp:RequireFieldValidator`'s and a templated `Asp:Login`.